# nodes exist in database and "page not found" - drupal6

Tags: nodes, routes

I have a drupal6 site and have a content type "resource" with more than 500 nodes.
there are some nodes "almost 15 nodes" from this type of "resource" when open it tell me "page not found", also when edit it tell "page not found" and when delete, set message "success deleted " and not deleted

although, theses nodes exist in "Data Base" in "node" table
and when try function "node_load(nid)", didn't work.

i tried search for 2 days and tried many many solutions and still couldn't reach to solution.

i hope if there is who help me
Thanks

Comment: Do you have backup of your database? it seems to be corrupted. Check the revision to know what happened

Comment: no, my fault. it is a site built from 5 years